# Mathematical notation for high and low value?

Tags: notation

I'm doing some trigonometry and am answering a question about the unit circle. In one question, I want to prelude my answer with an intuition. This leads me to the question:

Are there mathematical symbol for high and low? (I'm a bit lazy to write "high" and "low"). If there aren't, any suggestions?

Example (I'm obviously handwaving, and I'm not sure to what extent the example is even correct, it is just for the context of using the symbol):

**In words**: I want to show that a high to very high x-coordinate value in the 1st quadrant of the unit circle is a low to very low x-coordinate value when added with $\pi/2$ as that is a 90 degree anti-clockwise rotation (see the image for an example where x is high but not very high). For y the opposite is the case.

**Mathematically I'd write:**

$$P(cos(high\ x), sin(low\ y)$$ (note: my textbook says that $cos(\theta)$ is the x-coordinate for a point on the unit circle, because of this I feel comfortable leaving $\theta$ out of it and just overload the meaning of x with x-coordinate and with angle of x-coordinate, vice-versa for y. When I program in Java I do it all the time, here as well, I wouldn't do this if I'd need to communicate this to someone else but this example was written to myself only, I wouldn't use a high or low symbol in the first place if I'd write to someone else, but I'd like a shorthand for myself that has some historical backing to it)

$$Q = \pi/2 + P = 90\ degrees\ {anti-clockwise} + P$$

$$\text{So } Q(-sin(low\ y), cos(high\ x))$$

In visualization: $P = B, Q = C$ (I never used the GeoGebra viz tool before).

Visualization:
[image: Visualization of Exmaple]

Comment: It appears that you want "high" and "low" to indicate relative sizes of $x$ and $y$ coordinates. For clarity, you'd probably want to separate-out this comparison, writing something like "[some expression], with $x>y$" in favor of "high $x$, low $y$". ... That said, it makes no sense to write "$(\cos(\text{high}\;x), \sin(\text{low}\;y))$"; the trig functions are not being applied to $x$ and $y$ values, but to some angle, as in "$(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$".

Comment: ah... or using the $>>$ operator. The correctness of the example is not the point. But speaking about the example: if I'd define $x$ or $y$ to an angle value, I could use them. It's just a label, I feel no need to be *that* standardized about it (unless I'd want to communicate it to other people but this example was taken from my personal notes).

Comment: I honestly have no idea what your example is trying to say. Can you explain it in words?

Comment: A high x value starting in the 1st quadrant of the unit circle becomes a low x value in the second quadrant. For y it's the opposite. The visualization is an example of that.

Comment: *"The correctness of the example is not the point"* ... I get that; the parenthetical before it suggests not taking it literally. ... In any case, if you want specific advice about notational alternatives, you should explain (in words) what exactly you are trying to convey with this high/low stuff. Your comment introduces "$\gg$", which typically means that one value is *orders of magnitude* larger than another. Your example doesn't convey this, but maybe you don't intend this; I can't tell. Be sure to add any and all clarifications to the body of the question; comments are easily overlooked.

Comment: Ah fair point, I'm being too loose with the idea of $>>$ then. I just thought it meant a lot larger, with "a lot" being context dependent. I edited my answer.

Comment: Does $cos(high x)$ mean "the cosine of an angle such that $x$ is high (i.e. close to $1$)" ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

(I'll accept this answer within a month from now if no one is going to answer it, I invite Blue to write an answer)

Based on the comment one potential way to do this is stating something like:

Let there be two angles $x, y | x > 10y$.

For cognitive clarity (i.e. reducing cognitive load), it'd be smarter to use $a$ and $z$ as variables, such that you can more easily recognize the high and low value.

Let there be two angles $a, z | 10a < z$.

This means the same, but my brain intuitively gets it more. And since math notation is based *to some extent* on context with the purpose to aid ones memory, I think this is a slightly better way to write it down.

If one were to communicate to other people, I'd write:

$\theta_a, \theta_z | 10\theta_a < \theta_z$